# Using Java, how to get the 'ActualWidth' of the text of a TextBlock and use it?

Tags: java, xaml, width, textblock

See subject title.

I have a method in Java that draws a TextBlock element:

```
public void drawTextBlock(String text) {
    Element textBlock = new Element("TextBlock", Ns.getDefaultNamespace());
    textBlock.setAttribute(new Attribute("Text", text));
}
```

However, the `Width` of the `TextBlock` must be exactly as wide as the width of the text I give to it.

How would this be done?

Comment: What are you doing exactly? Are you generating XAML from Java?

Comment: Clemmer, why did you remove my 'thanks' from my question? Saying 'thanks' is a matter of common decency when addressing people.

Comment: salutations and thanks should not be included in questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: I disagree with that and I agree with JohnH there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set the width. Unless the `HorizontalAlignment` is `Stretch` (which is the default) The width of a `TextBlock` automatically adjusts to the size of the text it contains (as long as there is enough space to contain the `TextBlock` of course). So you just need to set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`, `Right` or `Center`

Comment: That has certainly fixed it. Thanks.